# Is there a OSX system app out there enabling me to use Tor as the only internet connection?

Tags: mac

I'd like to use Tor for all internet connections on my Mac. Therefore I'm hunting for an App which enables me to configure my Mac's internet connection globally.

All I've found till now is, that this is not possible and/or not secure and I'll have to use the Tor Browser.

But I can't see why this shouldn't work or sould be more unsecure? And I'm wondering if you using such an App right now and if, which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor (the underlying protocol) only supports [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) connections, whereas lots of applications require [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol). To enable *all* of your outgoing connections to use Tor, you'd have to translate any UDP traffic to use TCP. (Whether this is possible would be its own topic. I don't know the answer.)

As an alternative, have a look at [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/), which is a standalone OS in which all traffic is sent over Tor. The global configuration is done for you. (The caveat being that you can still only use applications that support TCP.)